# Convert integer to datetime in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I used
`pd.to_numeric (df['dates'], downcast = 'integer')`
to convert a datetime64 to int64 but if I want to convert it back to datetime format, what should I do?
Earlier it was in format: 2020-02-19 but after conversion it is now 1582070400000000000. I can't find a way to revert it back to datetime64.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])`?

Comment: And you didn't consider reading up on documentation how to convert to a datetime in Pandas ( https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime ). Say,  `pd.to_datetime(1582070400000000000)`?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime` works for me, `pd.Timestamp(1582070400000000000)` also works.

Answer (score 2):

## Pandas to_datatime does the trick

See example:

```
import pandas as pd
# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates' : pd.date_range('01-01-2021','01-10-2021',freq='D')})
# To numeric, as you did
df['numeric'] = pd.to_numeric (df['dates'] , downcast = 'integer')
# Back to date
df['back_do_date'] = pd.to_datetime( df['numeric'] )
```

gives the DataFrame: df

```
    dates       numeric             back_do_date
0   2021-01-01  1609459200000000000 2021-01-01
1   2021-01-02  1609545600000000000 2021-01-02
2   2021-01-03  1609632000000000000 2021-01-03
3   2021-01-04  1609718400000000000 2021-01-04
4   2021-01-05  1609804800000000000 2021-01-05
5   2021-01-06  1609891200000000000 2021-01-06
6   2021-01-07  1609977600000000000 2021-01-07
7   2021-01-08  1610064000000000000 2021-01-08
8   2021-01-09  1610150400000000000 2021-01-09
9   2021-01-10  1610236800000000000 2021-01-10
```